# Unable to use Assets in in HTTPS

Tags: assets, ssl

Changed my Control Panel to https, but assets doesn't show images nor let me load. In http it works fine, but when i change the address to https, according to firebug, the address https://myurl.com/index.php gets redirected. I already have `$config['assets_site_url'] = "/index.php";` on my config file, so what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also worth noting that using protocol relative ( //domain.com ) will work in most situations. This allows you to not have to hardcode a protocol specific url. Helpful when you're using the same code on a live HTTPS site as well as a local, HTTP site.

Comment: This is the correct answer IMHO because you can swap between protocols with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure your site url and all of your url paths in your admin > general configuration are https:// and also go to your content > file > file upload preferences and make sure that the url path there is https://. Also if you are hard coding the urls in your html head when attaching assets like css and js make sure those are https:// as well.

Comment: This worked for me. I added that line to the config.php file and it sorted the issue. Thanks.